# Convert function to single line list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to convert this function, list comprehension combination into a single list comprehension (so that `keep` is not needed)?

```
def keep(list, i, big):
    for small in list[i+1:]:
        if 0 == big % small:
            return False
    return True

multiples[:] = [n for i,n in enumerate(multiples) if keep(multiples, i, n)]
```

Comment: What does multiples look like?

Comment: why do you want to convert? What's wrong with your function? List comprehensions are meant to make things clearer/, not obscure/.

Comment: Can you provide some sample I/O?

Comment: Maybe some more descriptive variable names might be in order, but it's not _that_ obscure...

Comment: No one wins at code golf.  Are you trying to reduce the complexity from **O** ( n^2 )?  If so, you're trying to redesign things, not just fiddle around with syntax.

Comment: The answer to your question is probably yes, but doing so would make the code much less legible. Right now the code is only 6 lines of code and it is clear what it is trying to accomplish. The fact that you can fit it all into one complicated comprehension does not necessarily mean it is the best way to code it.

Comment: Code golf is awesome. :P

Comment: Hey guys, I am just learning python and was trying to understand list comprehension a little better. Feel free to edit the question if you want to introduce better variable names :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is it:

```
multiples[:] = [n for i,n in enumerate(multiples) 
                       if all(n % small for small in multiples[i+1:])]
```

Comment: +1 This looks more readable than original code for me. That is somewhat subjective, though.

Answer (score 2):

`multiples[:] = [n for i, n in enumerate(multiples) if 0 not in [n % other for other in multiples[i+1:]]`

Advisible? Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to learn to not use names like `list` in your code. Remember also the "first make it work, then optimize". If you continue to learn things, it is likely that in any case after one month you are not any more happy with your code. Try to make readable code. For that it helps if you can (heaven forbid!) read your own code after putting it aside for few weeks.

That said, it is actually more readable sometimes to make list comprehension, but often you can do it only after writing more stupid version of code.